# Converting json to a js array

Tags: javascript, arrays, type-conversion

I want to convert my json file into js array. It works but when I define questions array it does not. Should I leave it like it is? Because in a console I get a error that question is not defined. Should I provide more code(How I display)?

json:

```
[
    {
      "question": "Inside which HTML element do we put the JavaScript??",
      "choice1": "<script>",
      "choice2": "<javascript>",
      "choice3": "<js>",
      "choice4": "<scripting>",
      "answer": 1
    },
    {
      "question": "What is the correct syntax for referring to an external script called 'xxx.js'?",
      "choice1": "<script href='xxx.js'>",
      "choice2": "<script name='xxx.js'>",
      "choice3": "<script src='xxx.js'>",
      "choice4": "<script file='xxx.js'>",
      "answer": 3
    },
    {
      "question": " How do you write 'Hello World' in an alert box?",
      "choice1": "msgBox('Hello World');",
      "choice2": "alertBox('Hello World');",
      "choice3": "msg('Hello World');",
      "choice4": "alert('Hello World');",
      "answer": 4
    }
  ]
```

js:

```
     // with this defined code does not work
        let questions = [];
    
    fetch("questions.json")
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((loadedQuestions) => {
        questions = loadedQuestions;
        startGame();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });

    startGame = () => {
  numOfQuestions = 0;
  NumBack = 0;

  availableQuestions = [...questions];
  getNewQuestion();
};

getNewQuestion = () => {
  if (availableQuestions.length === 0 || numOfQuestions >= MAX_QUESTIONS) {
    //go to the end page
    return window.location.assign("/end.html");
  }
  numOfQuestions++;
  console.log(numOfQuestions);

  // random question
  const questionIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableQuestions.length);
  currentQuestion = availableQuestions[questionIndex];
  question.innerText = currentQuestion.question;

  choices.forEach((choice) => {
    const number = choice.dataset["number"];
    choice.innerText = currentQuestion["choice" + number];
  });

  availableQuestions.splice(questionIndex, 1);
};
```

Then I use other methods to move.

First with devinition, secound without.

[image: With devinition]

[image: No devinition]

Comment: Please add the `startGame` function. Also, right before calling `startGame()`, what's the output of `console.log(loadedQuestions)`?

Comment: I added. Can you take a look?

Comment: change `startGame = () => {` to `function startGame() {`, do the same with for `function getNewQuestion () {`

Answer (score 1):

When you parse JSON using the [response.json()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json) method it is an asynchronous call, so you would need to do something like:

```
  fetch("questions.json")
  .then(async (res) => {
    return await res.json();
  })
  .then((loadedQuestions) => {
    questions = loadedQuestions;
    startGame();
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

Comment: But still if i define question arrey it does not work and if i comment definition it works but shows error that array is not defined. You can see it on a screenshots.

Comment: *'When you parse JSON ... it is an asynchronous call,'* this is too general a statement and not true, edited to make it specific to the `response.json()` call.